# separate split string with javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have this 4 task type of string:

```
ManagerTask
CoordinatorTask
BossTask
EmployTask
```

I need a method/regexp to split/separate these strings: The result should be:

```
Manager Task
Coordinator Task
Boss Task
Employ Task
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regex to match anything before task and the 'Task' and add space between these to matched groups:

```js
const modify = text => text.replace(/(.+)(Task)/, '$1 $2');

console.log(modify('ManagerTask'));
console.log(modify('CoordinatorTask'));
console.log(modify('BossTask'));
console.log(modify('EmployTask'));
```

Also if you needed general solution for this issue you can use:

```js
const modify = text => text
  // Find all capital letters and add space before them
  .replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1')
  // Remove the first space - otherwise result would be for example ' OfficeManagerTask'
  .substring(1);

console.log(modify('OfficeManagerTask'));
console.log(modify('AngryBossTask'));

console.log(modify('ManagerTask'));
console.log(modify('CoordinatorTask'));
console.log(modify('BossTask'));
console.log(modify('EmployTask'));
```

Comment: The best and shortest response. Thank you!

Comment: Consider using the updated answer for possible future cases.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```js
function splitString(str){

  return str.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf("T"))+" "+str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("T"));

}


console.log(splitString("ManagerTask"));
```

Comment: you response is fine but i can not use concatenation with eslint. Please can you change the code with template `` instead of concatenation?  thank you

Answer (score 1):

```js
var taskStrs = ['ManagerTask', 'CoordinatorTask', 'BossTask', 'EmployTask', "TaskMakerTask"];

function formatTaskName(task) {
  var lastTaskInd = task.lastIndexOf("Task");
  if(lastTaskInd == -1) {
    return task;
  }
  return task.substring(0,lastTaskInd) + " " + task.substring(lastTaskInd);
}

for(var i = 0; i < taskStrs.length; i++) {
  console.log(formatTaskName(taskStrs[i]));
}
```

Comment: @tomatilo, The jQuery has been removed, it was only to show the result of the Javascript function